# Slack Integration Invalid_Auth (for team slash command)

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm trying to build a slack integration slash command for my team. I get the request sent to the server, but then it throws and `invalid_auth` error. If I'm just building a slash integration for my team, I should just need the Token provided for the slash command, correct? I'm not sure why the `invalid_auth` problem is occurring.

The docs aren't helping me, but if anyone has a pointer, would be much appreciated.

> ex. using the node-slack-upload library

```
var slack = new Slack(TOKEN_HERE)
// do stuff like slack.upload({...})
```

Comment: Are you using the slash command verifier or the actual API token you generate at the beginning?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?  I am experiencing the same issues.  I am using the actual API token generated in the Slack admin tool.